# Query using multiple secondary indexes on the same table

Tags: sqlalchemy, google-cloud-spanner

I want to make a Spanner SQL query on a single table with `WHERE` statements using different multiple secondary indexes that exist on the table (`prop1_index` and `prop2_index`).

I think it's not possible to specify multiple `FORCE_INDEX` for the same `FROM` table (see below). So maybe there are SQL ways to chain/combine/join multiple `SELECT` statements that all use different secondary indexes.

```sql
SELECT
  c.uid,
  c.prop1,
  c.prop2
FROM
  mycolumn@{FORCE_INDEX=prop1_index} AS c  -- Also need `{FORCE_INDEX=prop2_index}` here
WHERE
  c.prop1 BETWEEN 100
  AND 101
  AND c.prop2 BETWEEN 50
  AND 1000
```

Ideally, I also looking to perform the same using SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right. Multiple indices for the same FROM is not supported.

However, you can use a self-join to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT
  c.uid,
  c1.prop1,
  c2.prop2
FROM
  mycolumn@{FORCE_INDEX=prop1_index} AS c1
HASH JOIN
  mycolumn@{FORCE_INDEX=prop2_index} AS c2
ON c1.uid = c2.uid
WHERE
  c1.prop1 BETWEEN 100
  AND 101
  AND c2.prop2 BETWEEN 50
  AND 1000
```

Also, if these two indices are always used together, you can also consider combining them into one index.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I actually have ~10-15 properties columns on which I would like to apply BETWEEN filters. Is that possible to chain those in SQL?

Comment: After a few tests, it looks like the JOIN operation makes the query duration quite long. It's just not possible in my context to combine the indexes since I have 10-15 properties columns and potentially we are looking to make queries with only a subset of them (and not always the same subset).

Comment: Do you think there is a chance for the Spanner backend to support and optimize better this kind of queries? By allowing multi secondary indexes in the same FROM clause for example and optimize it under the hood.

Comment: What alternative execution strategy would you like to see from permitting multiple indexes in the FROM clause?  It seems that supporting multiple indexes would lead to the same execution strategy as Hailong's query - use each index for the relevant predicate and take the intersection of qualifying rows.  Note that the query assumes column "uid" is the primary key of the table.

Typo: c.uid in the select list should be c1 (or, equally, c2)

Comment: I think as you said there is no other strategy than performing the intersection indeed. In that case supporting multiple indexes would only be to make the SQL query easier to read and less verbose (useful when dealing with 5-10 different columns for example).

Comment: Just curious - when you say "makes the duration quite long", is it the case that "it is even slower than querying without index"? I wonder if you can get a profile of the query and see why it is slow.